# JS Regex to match a string within HTML tags that aren't <a>

Tags: javascript, regex

I am using jQuery to highlight abbreviations within an article, and am struggling with my regex.

I am trying to match specific text that is a word within a HTML tag (and not within an attribute like `<img src="abbr" />`), not part of another word and not already within an `<a>` tag.

I will then wrap that with an `<abbr>` tag and a link to the glossary.

I've gotten a little of the way, my current regex looks like this:

```
(\>[^\>]*\W)abbr(\W[^\>=]*\<)
```

Where "abbr" is the abbreviation I'm trying to match. This sort of works, but not if the abbr is the first word of a line, or if it is within an `<a>` tag.

These instances of "abbr" I would want to match:

```
<p>Lorem abbr ipsum</p>
<p>abbr lorem abbr</p>
<ul>
  <li>abbr abbr</li>
  <li>abbr</li>
</ul>
```

Whereas I don't want to match any of these:

```
<p><a href="abbr.html">abbr</a></p>
<img src="abbr.jpg" />
<p>Lormabbripsum</p>
```

To do this I am selecting all the of HTML within my article with the aim to do a string replace. My JS looks like this

```
$.getJSON("glossaryjson", function (data) {
    var str = $('.article-body').html();

    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

        var regex = new RegExp("(\>[^\p>]*\\W)" + data[i].name + "(\\W[^\>=]*\<)");

        str = str.replace(regex, '$1<abbr title="' + data[i].desc + '"><a href="/glossary?f=' + data[i].letter + '">' + data[i].name + '</a></abbr>$2');
            }

    $('.article-body').html(str);
});
```

Comment: [You can't parse (X)HTML with regex.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1529630)

Comment: ... but either way, showing us the code you have so far would help quite a bit.

Comment: @Oriol is entirely correct... wish I could remember where I saw this, and who to credit it to...  Rule 1: don't use RegEx to parse HTML. Rule 2: if you still want to parse HTML with RegEx, see rule 1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use word boundaries '\b' to stop it from finding abbreciations in the middle of words. However, it's not perfect. Suppose you were looking for I.A. It would find a match in C.I.A. because periods are part of word boundaries.

Further, we can use positive lookaheads (LA) and negative lookaheads (NLA) to *look ahead* and make a decision based on the contents.

I don't think regex is ideal for this because of the word boundary issue and because when casting such a wide net across an html document, things can get hairy (if you non-ideal html)

```
\babbr\b(?=(?![^>]*<\/a>)[^>]*)

\b             # Token: \b
                 # word boundary
abbr           # Literal abbr
\b             # Token: \b
                 # word boundary
(?=            # Opens LA
 (?!           # Opens NLA
  [^>]*        # Negated Character class (excludes the characters within)
                 # None of: >
                 # * repeats zero or more times
  <\/a>        # Literal </a>
 )             # Closes NLA
 [^>]*         # Negated Character class (excludes the characters within)
                 # None of: >
                 # * repeats zero or more times
                 # Literal <
)              # Closes LA
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay with using jQuery, you can find elements that match what you want (not `<a>` elements and not parent elements), then use only the ones with text that your regex matches. For instance...

```
$(':not(a, :has(*))').filter(function(i,e){return !!e.innerHTML.match(/\babbr\b/)})
```

Otherwise, you'd just have to something similar...

```
function filterAbbr() {
    var all = document.getElementsByTagName('*');
    var filter = [];
    for(var i=0; i<all.length; i++) {
        if(!all[i].children.length && all[i].tagName != 'A') {
            filter.push(all[i]);
        }
    }
    all = [];
    for(var i=0; i<filter.length; i++) {
        if(filter[i].innerHTML.match(/\babbr\b/)) {
            all.push(filter[i]);
        }
    }
    return all;
}
```